# How to find unique elements from 2 array of objects in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, mean

I have following 2 arrays,

I want to compare empIds value with allEmps id value and want to push unique value to a new array,

```
var empIds = [ 123, 321 ];

var allEmps = [ [{id: 123, name: 'Raj'}], [{id: 321, name: 'Raju'}], [{id: 931, name: 'Rahul'}];

Expected output:
                [{id: 931, name: 'Rahul'}]
```

My try,

```
gridData = [];
empIds.forEach(id => {
  allEmps.forEach(series => {
    if (series[0].id !== id) {
      gridData.push(series[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

But these code is giving duplicate data also, can anyone pls correct my code .Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicates are caused by iterating over `empIds` and over `allEmps` each time.

Try changing the order and for each employee record checking if it's ID is not in `empIds`

```
gridData = [];
allEmps.forEach(series => {
  if (empIds.indexOf(series[0].id) === -1) { // ID not found in empIds
    gridData.push(series[0]);
  }
});
// gridData = [ {id: 931, name: "Rahul"} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var empIds = [ 123, 321 ];
var allEmps = [ [{id: 123, name: 'Raj'}], [{id: 321, name: 'Raju'}], [{id: 931, name: 'Rahul'}];

var gridData = allEmps.map(arr => arr[0]).filter(emp => !empIds.includes(emp.id))
```

You can do it by steps:

```js
var objs = allEmps.map(arr => arr[0]) 
// returns "[{"id":123,"name":"Raj"},{"id":321,"name":"Raju"},{"id":931,"name":"Rahul"}]"
```

You don't need to have array inside the array.
Then filter the ones that are not part of empIds:

```js
objs.filter(emp => !empIds.includes(emp.id))
```